# guardar datetimepicker en mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

Hola buenos dias a todos, junto con saludarlos queria ver si me podian orientar un poquito: tengo un proyecto en capas c# y mysql, tengo que guardar una fecha desde un datetimepicker a un campo datetime de mysql, pero me muestra estos errores: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] en mi capa de datos tengo un metodo para insertar datos:

```
 public datosProfesional(int idProfesional, int idLogin, string rut_profesional, string nombres_profesional, string ape_pat, string ape_mat, MySqlDateTime fecha_nacimiento, string sexo, string direccion, int telefono, string email, string profesion, string especialidad, string codigo_autorizacion, string observaciones, string textoBusqueda)
    {
        this.IdProfesional = idProfesional; //AUTOINCREMENTAL
        this.IdLogin = IdLogin;
        this.Rut_profesional = rut_profesional;
        this.Nombres_profesional = nombres_profesional;
        this.Ape_pat = ape_pat;
        this.Ape_mat = ape_mat;
        this.Fecha_nacimiento = fecha_nacimiento;
        this.Sexo = sexo;
        this.Direccion = direccion;
        this.Telefono = telefono;
        this.Email = email;
        this.Profesion = profesion;
        this.Especialidad = especialidad;
        this.Codigo_autorizacion = codigo_autorizacion;
        this.Observaciones = observaciones;
        this.TextoBusqueda = textoBusqueda;
    }

    //METODO INSERTAR
    public string insertarProfesional(datosProfesional profesional)
    {
        string respuesta = "";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection();

        try
        {
            //CADENA DE CONEXION
            con.ConnectionString = conexion.cadenaConexion;

            //ABRIMOS LA CONEXION
            con.Open();

            //COMANDO PARA EJECUTAR CONSULTA
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;

            //LLAMAMOS A LA CONSULTA O PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO
            cmd.CommandText = "spInsertarProfesional";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            //DECLARAMOS LOS PARAMETROS QUE SON IGUALES A LOS QUE TENEMOS EN EL SP
            MySqlParameter parIdProfesional = new MySqlParameter();
            parIdProfesional.ParameterName = "@idprofesional";
            parIdProfesional.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32;
            parIdProfesional.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parIdProfesional);

            //14 VARIABLES

            MySqlParameter parLogin = new MySqlParameter();
            parLogin.ParameterName = "@idlogin";
            parLogin.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32;
            parLogin.Value = profesional.IdLogin;
            parLogin.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parLogin);


            MySqlParameter parRutProf = new MySqlParameter();
            parRutProf.ParameterName = "@rutprofesional";
            parRutProf.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar;
            parRutProf.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            parRutProf.Size = 25;
            parRutProf.Value = profesional.Rut_profesional;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parRutProf);

            MySqlParameter parNombreProf = new MySqlParameter();
            parNombreProf.ParameterName = "@nombres";
            parNombreProf.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar;
            parNombreProf.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            parNombreProf.Size = 100;
            parNombreProf.Value = profesional.Nombres_profesional;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parNombreProf);

            MySqlParameter parApePat = new MySqlParameter();
            parApePat.ParameterName = "@apepat";
            parApePat.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar;
            parApePat.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            parApePat.Size = 50;
            parApePat.Value = profesional.Ape_pat;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parApePat);

            MySqlParameter parApeMat = new MySqlParameter();
            parApeMat.ParameterName = "@apemat";
            parApeMat.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar;
            parApeMat.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            parApeMat.Size = 50;
            parApeMat.Value = profesional.Ape_mat;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parApeMat);

            MySqlParameter parFechaNac = new MySqlParameter();
            parFechaNac.ParameterName = "@fecha_nac";
            parFechaNac.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.DateTime;
            parFechaNac.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            parFechaNac.Value = profesional.Fecha_nacimiento;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parFechaNac);

            MySqlParameter parSexo = new MySqlParameter();
            parSexo.ParameterName = "@sexo";
            parSexo.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar;
            parSexo.Size = 45;
            parSexo.Value = profesional.Sexo;
            parSexo.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parSexo);

            MySqlParameter parDireccion = new MySqlParameter();
            parDireccion.ParameterName = "@direccion";
            parDireccion.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar;
            parDireccion.Size = 150;
            parDireccion.Value = profesional.Direccion;
            parDireccion.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parDireccion);

            MySqlParameter parEmail = new MySqlParameter();
            parEmail.ParameterName = "@email";
            parEmail.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar;
            parEmail.Size = 150;
            parEmail.Value = profesional.Email;
            parEmail.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parEmail);

            MySqlParameter parFono = new MySqlParameter();
            parFono.ParameterName = "@telefono";
            parFono.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32;
            parFono.Size = 9;
            parFono.Value = profesional.Telefono;
            parFono.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parFono);

            MySqlParameter parProfesion = new MySqlParameter();
            parProfesion.ParameterName = "@profesion";
            parProfesion.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar;
            parProfesion.Size = 150;
            parProfesion.Value = profesional.Profesion;
            parProfesion.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parProfesion);

            MySqlParameter parEspecialdiad = new MySqlParameter();
            parEspecialdiad.ParameterName = "@especialidad";
            parEspecialdiad.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar;
            parEspecialdiad.Size = 150;
            parEspecialdiad.Value = profesional.Especialidad;
            parEspecialdiad.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parEspecialdiad);

            MySqlParameter parCodAutoriz = new MySqlParameter();
            parCodAutoriz.ParameterName = "@codigo_aut";
            parCodAutoriz.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar;
            parCodAutoriz.Size = 45;
            parCodAutoriz.Value = profesional.Codigo_autorizacion;
            parCodAutoriz.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parCodAutoriz);

            MySqlParameter parObservaciones = new MySqlParameter();
            parObservaciones.ParameterName = "@observaciones";
            parObservaciones.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.MediumText;
            parObservaciones.Value = profesional.Observaciones;
            parObservaciones.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parObservaciones);           

            //EJECUCION DEL COMANDO
            respuesta = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1 ? "ok" : "no se pudo";


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            respuesta = ex.Message;
        }

        //CIERRE DE CONEXION
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open) con.Close();
        }

        //RETORNAMOS LA VARIABLE DEL METODO
        return respuesta;
    }
```

este es el codigo de mi capa negocio:

```
  //INSERTAR
    public static string insertarProfesional(
        int idLogin,
        string rut_profesional,
        string nombres_profesional,
        string ape_pat,
        string ape_mat,
        MySqlDateTime fecha_nacimiento,
        string sexo,
        string direccion,
        int telefono, 
        string email,
        string profesion,
        string especialidad, 
        string codigo_autorizacion,
        string observaciones)
    {
        datosProfesional obj = new datosProfesional();
        obj.IdLogin = idLogin;
        obj.Rut_profesional = rut_profesional;
        obj.Nombres_profesional = nombres_profesional;
        obj.Ape_pat = ape_pat;
        obj.Ape_mat = ape_mat;
        obj.Fecha_nacimiento = fecha_nacimiento;
        obj.Sexo = sexo;
        obj.Direccion = direccion;
        obj.Telefono = telefono;
        obj.Email = email;
        obj.Profesion = profesion;
        obj.Especialidad = especialidad;
        obj.Codigo_autorizacion = codigo_autorizacion;
        obj.Observaciones = observaciones;


        return obj.insertarProfesional(obj);

    }
```

y el error lo tengo en el codigo de mi formulario:

```
if (this.isNuevo)
                {
                    respuesta = negociosProfesional.insertarProfesional(
                        Convert.ToInt32(this.txtId.Text),
                        //convert.toInt32(this.txtId.Text),
                        this.txtDocumento.Text,
                        this.txtNombre.Text,
                        this.txtApePat.Text,
                        this.txtApeMat.Text,
                        dtpFechaNacimiento.Value,
                        this.cmbSexo.Text,
                        this.txtDireccion.Text,
                        Convert.ToInt32(this.txtFono.Text),
                        this.txtEmail.Text,
                        this.txtProfesion.Text,
                        this.txtEspecialidad.Text,
                        this.txtObservaciones.Text,
                        this.txtEspecialidad.Text


                        );
                }
                else
                {
                    //respuesta = negociosProfesional.editarProfesional(this.txtDocumento.Text.Trim());
                }
            }
```

Saludos a todos y agradezco desde ya

Comment: Si no me equivoco un campo `DateTime` en Mysql requiere un string y no un datetime. intenta formatear la fecha, algo asi: `dtpFechaNacimiento.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss");`

Comment: hola estimado, gracias por tu tiempo, el tipo de campo en mysql es datetime, el parametro lo paso de esta manera:

Comment: MySqlParameter parFechaNacPaciente = new MySqlParameter();
                parFechaNacPaciente.ParameterName = "@fecha_nac";
                //parFechaNacPaciente.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.DateTime;
                parFechaNacPaciente.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar;
                parFechaNacPaciente.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                parFechaRegistro.Size = 45;
                parFechaRegistro.Value = paciente.Fecha_nac;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parFechaNacPaciente);

Comment: y en mi boton guardar, es donde me da el error: if (this.isNuevo)
                    {
                        respuesta = negocioPaciente.insertar(
                            //Convert.ToInt32(this.txtID.Text),
                           Convert.ToInt32( this.txtNumFicha.Text),
                           this.txtDocumento.Text,
                           this.txtNombres.Text,
                           this.txtApePat.Text,
                           this.txtApeMat.Text,
                           Convert.ToString(this.dtpFechaNac.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss")),